# Angular2 logging http response

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

service.ts

```
create(category: Category): Observable<Category> {

let body = JSON.stringify(category);
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'categories', body, options)
                .map(res =>  <Category> res.json() )
                .catch(handleError);

}
```

component.ts

```
    this.categoryService.create(this.category)
                 .subscribe(
                   c  => this.category = c,
                   error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
                   console.log("created category ID " + this.category.id); 
                   this.categories.push(this.category);
```

console writes "log created category ID undefined" but server returns with id. how to log the http response within service.ts itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.categoryService.create(this.category)
    .subscribe(
      c  =>{ this.category = c
             console.log("created category ID " + this.category.id);  //<<<access here
             this.categories.push(this.category); 
            },
      error =>  {this.errorMessage = <any>error)}
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the code that depends on the response move into `subscribe()`

```
         this.categoryService.create(this.category)
             .subscribe(
               c  => {
                  this.category = c;
                  console.log("created category ID " + this.category.id); 
                  this.categories.push(this.category); 
               }),
               error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

Comment: after moving `this.categories.push(this.category); ` inside it worked, thanks. However the log outside being invoked earlier than subscribe.

Comment: Ups, forgot to move that in as well.